# Controlling scroll of tables

Tags: html, css

Here I have two `<table>`s:

[image]
(at the bottom the gray box is the scroll bar.)

one is a table with long text, the other is a table with multiple `th` and `td`,

and here's the css for tables:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;

  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: block;
  max-width: -moz-fit-content;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

I'm fine with the second table's format; because there are many cells horizontally, it should be kept as scrollable,

but at the same time, I want to have the upper table to have its long continued text to make a line break inside the cell, because it is simply the long text that makes it overflow.

How can I achieve these two features at once?